# Can a known MD5 hash limit the search space for SHA1 collisions?

Tags: cryptography, hash

For a course in game theory, we are dealing with BitTorrent and alternative strategies (roughly alternative clients) we can employ to maximize our download speed. One strategy is to over-report the pieces we have and upload junk data.

Clients very quickly learned to deal with that, but looking at the spec I noticed that while each piece is checksummed/hashed using SHA1, the entire file (or all the files) are sometimes checksummed using MD5.

And that made me wonder if the fact that we sometimes have a MD5 hash of an entire file would make it easier to find collisions for individual pieces using SHA1?

Answer (score 5):

No.

MD5 and SHA1 are largely unrelated. Knowledge about one does not confer any knowledge about the other.